# Why does sorted not sort the array properly?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting

I'm trying to use sorted to sort a 2d array by its 4th value from biggest to smallest, but for some reason it's not sorting properly. It seems to sort two values correctly, but not much more. I've tried to look on the internet for how to use sorted but it seems that this should be sorting it correctly:

```
stuff = [['A', '15', '23', '5'], ['A', '15', '23', '2'], ['A', '15', '23', '17'], ['A', '15', '23', '16'], ['A', '15', '23', '12']]
stuff = sorted(stuff, key=lambda x: x[3], reverse = True)
print(stuff)
```

This is the output I get:
[['A', '15', '23', '5'], ['A', '15', '23', '2'], ['A', '15', '23', '17'], ['A', '15', '23', '16'], ['A', '15', '23', '12']]

Comment: Okay, and what's wrong with this result?

Comment: You need to convert to integer in the key function: i.e. `int(x[3])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `key` function is comparing string values. So, when it tries to compare `'2'` with `'17'`, it goes character by character, and since `'2' > '1'`, it thinks it has a greater value.

You can easily fix this by either using integers on the `stuff` array 4th item:

```py
stuff = [['A', '15', '23', 5], ['A', '15', '23', 2], ['A', '15', '23', 17], ['A', '15', '23', 16], ['A', '15', '23', 12]]
```

Or by calling `int` to convert from string to integers on the key function:

```py
stuff = sorted(stuff, key=lambda x: int(x[3]), reverse = True)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is sorted fine because lexicographically '5' is greater than '17'.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.